# How to enforce Authentication after successful SAML SSO login?

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, saml

Is it possible to force user to re-enter credentials in a SAML IDP after he has successfully login. This is part of the e-signature workflow where we want user to re-authenticate himself before continuing.

I am using keyCloak as IDP and to achieve this, in my SAML request I set ForceAuthn to true. Even though the flag is set to true, the IDP never asks user to provide credentials again. I believe its happening because there's a valid cookie available in the request.

The other option is to disable the Cookie "Authentication Flow" as shown in the image below (setting the first row in the grid as disabled), in which case the user has to provide credentials always.

[image]

So, Is it possible to keep Cookie "Authentication Flow" not disabled and yet force the user to provide credentials?

Comment: I guess, the way you want to make this happen in nothing to do with SAML SSO. This is something to do with KeyCloak session logic that you need to re-write or already provided as you stated above.

Comment: @Zeigeist yeah this has definitely something to do with keyCloak. I tried the same using Azure AD and it works perfectly fine